# JMeter + XML Parsing for URL

Tags: web-services, testing, jmeter

I am using JMeter to load test a sliver-light web application.

I need to hit a web service which returns a large XML file. I then need to go through this XML and pick up the URLS within one of the branches. These are then used to download media files.

The XML is just a list of video files that match the search conditions. Web service is WCF based and end with `url.com\name.svc`.

So step by step:

1. hit web service to get XML;
2. parse the URLs from the XML;
3. loop over these URLs downloading the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose you can combine and use in your scenario following components:

- [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to hit your web-service and then to send requests to extracted URLs;
- [XPath_Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) to extract all the required elements from xml-response (you have to right XPath query to use in this post-processor);
- [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate through the extracted URLs;
- [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener to save files per requested URLs.

Your schema may look like below one:

```
Thread Group
    ...
    HTTP Request                   // request to hit your web-service
        XPath Extractor
        Reference Name: testURL
        XPath query: ...
        Default value: NOT_FOUND
    Foreach Controller
    Input variable prefix: testURL
    Output variable name: url
    Add "_" before number? True
        HTTP Sampler              // request to download files per extracted urls
        Path: ${url}
            Save Responses to a file
        ...
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you Alies, you've put me on the right path and now have it working

Comment: Nice if so. Suppose you can at least [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) then.

Comment: Cant upvote just yet, havnt enough rep, I will come back and do so once I get there, cheers